# Is beta.apple.com running on Rails?

Tags: beta-seed-program

The error page is standard Rails error page, and the web server uses Phusion Passenger on Apache.

I guess it's probably running on Ruby on Rails? Very unexpected from Apple.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to [builtwith](http://builtwith.com/?https%3A%2F%2Fbeta.apple.com%2Fsp%2Fbetaprogram%2F) it is running rails.